# Chrome redirects stderr onto a open Terminal

Tags: google-chrome, gnome-terminal

## Issue

On one screen I have a Terminal open with Tmux running and on the other screen I have Chrome running (most of the time on a StackExchange's website).
Recently Chrome started outputting garbage on my Terminal, like right now:

```
[2805:15952:0212/161511:ERROR:cert_verify_proc_nss.cc(985)] CERT_PKIXVerifyCert for static.re-markit00.re-markit.co failed err=-8181
```

Chrome has been run from the Unity interface but its std-error is somehow redirected to my Terminal.

Can anyone guess what the heck is going on here? O.o

## `pstree` dump

[Link](https://gist.github.com/Atcold/88f4fe5ffff9b7a1d0b09b1a42cab36e) to a gist.

Comment: Did you ever run Chrome from your terminal? Or opened a URL or something using `xdg-open`, etc.? Add the output of `pstree -psa $(pgrep -o google-chrome)` to the post, please.

Comment: @muru, "Chrome has been run from the Unity interface but its std-error is somehow redirected to my Terminal." as pointed out in the question. I've added the output of the command you suggested.

Comment: I saw that. But Chrome re-uses existing processes, so if you did start it from the terminal and didn't close it properly, running it from Unity would still use that old process. Sigh. The Google Chrome command is just `chrome`, so `pgrep` didn't match anything. `pstree -psa $(pgrep -o chrome)` would be better.

Comment: @muru, I've updated the gist with the command you suggested. Let me know if you can figure out anything. Thank you.